# how to use gitlab to share files and folders between projects

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, cicd

I have a question to ask but ill explain my plan/requirement first

I have started on new company

I have been tasked to migrate a lot of microservices running on swarm to Kubernetes

there are about 50 microservices running now

right now we are using consul as key/value store for configuration files

due to a lot of mistakes in designing infrastructure, our swarm is not stable ( failing overlays and so on)

developers want to have sub-versioning on configuration as well but in a specific way

1. one project for all config files
2. they don't want to go through building stages
3. there are some applications that read live configurations (
   changes occur regularly )

so I need to centralize the configuration and create a project for this task

I store Kubernetes manifests GitLab-ci files and app configurations there

when I include ci files in the target project I can't access config and Kube manifests ( submodule is not acceptable by developers )

I'm planning to use helm instead of kubectl for deployment

my biggest challenge is to provide the configuration live ( as the developer pushes it applies on cm )

am I on the right track?
any suggestion on how to achieve my goal?

I expect to be able to deploy projects and use multiple files and folders from other projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a ci file like this in your devops repo, this job should commit the config file to your repo when config changed.

```
commit-config-file-to-devops-repo:
  script: "command to commit config file to your devops repo"
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    changes:
      - path/some-config-file.json
      - configs/*
```

2. change default ci file location to point to ci file in your devops repo
   https://192.168.64.188/help/ci/pipelines/settings#custom-cicd-configuration-path

   > my/path/.my-custom-file.yml@mygroup/another-project
3. setup pipeline, apply config to k8s when file commited.
   Personally I use `argocd` to sync helm chart to k8s, you can do it your way.
4. Read live configurations is normally not recommended, because changing config may cause error.
   When using k8s, it is better to create `configmap` and inject config into environment variables
   Then use `rollout` mechanism to restart the app.
5. Howeven, if you are using configmap volume
   It will auto update config file when you change config
   https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically

Comment: thank you for taking the time to Answer
I got the basic ide and will try it asap